# Redirecting to Login page after Login

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using Forms Authentication with this code

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms defaultUrl="Dashboard.aspx" loginUrl="Login.aspx" slidingExpiration="true" timeout="60" />
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
      <allow users="*" />
    </authorization>
```

Here problem is after successful login it is redirecting again to login page, If I do this for 3 or 4 times then it is redirecting me to Default page.

Comment: I see it's Web Forms.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the Forms Authentication you can use the ReturnUrl querystring in your login page:

```
var returnUrl = Request.QueryString["ReturnURL"];
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl)){
   returnUrl = "~/";
}
Response.Redirect(returnUrl);
```

If you are not using it you should behave as it does: When you redirect the user to the login page add a querystring with the referrer page.

```
//**Remember to url encode it!**
var returnUrl = Server.UrlEncode(Request.Url.PathAndQuery);
Response.Redirect("~/login.aspx?ReturnURL=" + returnUrl);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  If it works, add back your other attributes.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="Login.aspx" name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH" />
</authentication>
```

EDIT:
After a successful login, a cookie is created that holds the authentication ticket.  That ticket is encrypted. When requesting a page, the decryption is done by the FormsAuthenticationModule class.  I've had instances where I had to add the configuration below if it didn't exist or remove that configuration if it did exist.

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules>
        <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
    </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: thanks, but where I need to include this tag in my web.config??

Comment: Sorry, inside <system.webServer>.  I'll update my answer.